# Free or affordable unit test for C (/ C++) with code parsing and stub generation

Tags: c++, c, software-testing, unit-tests

"Free" means [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis); "affordable" means up to $100.

I am currently using [Vectorcast](https://www.vectorcast.com/) at work, and would love to use something similar on my home coding projects (which tend to be C, but are occasionally C++).

I can't afford thousands for a Vectorcast license, so am looking for a cheaper alternative.

Vectorcast parses my code (probably using Clang or similar) and can generate stubs for all functions, other than that which I am testing (the UUT).

I can then visually choose, for the entire call tree of my UUT (functions which it calls, then functions which they call, etc), whether to stub them, or execute the actual code. This allows me to perform unit test and/or (partial) integration test.

If I stub them, I can specify expected inputs, which the test harness checks, and provide return values.

There's more, but that's the gist of it.

Preferably for Windows, but I will also accept Linux

Comment: Would something with no need to generate stubs also a possibility? I use [`hipposmocks`](https://app.assembla.com/spaces/hippomocks/wiki/Tutorial_3_0).

Comment: This looks very promising, although I fear that I will only work for C++, and not for C (do you know if it can mock C like (non-member) functions?). I will spend some time with the tutorial and get back to you. Thanks